# Sobrescribir parametros visual basic

Tags: vb.net

Mi programa tendrá una serie de parametros que son los siguientes ejemplo:

```
Public Module Program

    Public h As String = "[host]"
    Public port As Integer = "[port]"
    Public meltf As String = "[M]"
    Public Name As String = "[vn]"
    Public Y As String = "/j|n\"

End Module
```

Y yo quiero desde mi otro programa sobrescrivir estos valores:

```
Public Class Form1
    //Aqui es donde sobrescribire los valores de mi programa de arriba.
End Class
```

Será un formulario donde ingresaré los valores y me los sobrescribivira en mi otro programa con los valores correspondientes. En principio no tengo ni idea como empezar a resolverlo en principio tendría que sobrescribivir simplemente eso los parametros. Ejemplo de resolución:

> Tengo dos programas. Uno donde ingreso los datos, pues esos datos
>   ingresados modificarán el valor de mi otro programa asignando a cada
>   campo su valor ya sea cada string ejemplo host = "127.0.0.1".

Si faltan mas detalles pues intentare corregirlo.

Comment: ¿se modificaran dentro del mismo proyecto?

Comment: son dos ejecutables por separado el formulario de abajo sobrescribe los valores del de arriba. Cuando dices se modificaran dentro del mismo proyecto te refieres a que forman parte del mismo proyecto pues sí. Uno es un modulo (programa consola) y otro un formulario. El formulario modificara los valores de mi modulo(programa consola) en visual basic. Espero haberme explicado mas o menos bien.

Comment: por ejemplo en cmd (esto es puede hacer por codigo) poner 'ejecutable1.exe -host 127.0.0.1 -port 80'

Comment: @HectorSeguro creo que deberías publicarlo como respuesta, mostrando cómo ejecutarlo y cómo recibir los valores

Answer (score 0):

Lo que entiendo con tu explicación es que quieres implementar un tipo `Template`

Se me ocurre la siguiente solución (hice un pequeño código de ejemplo):

[Link para descargar el fuente](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1NrUmB-KIz6aEIyOWtzV3lfWE0)

Diseñe el siguiente `form` para hacer el ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vamos por pasos:

1. Diseñar el `Template`, o la plantilla que será reemplazada por los valores
2. Obtener los valores.  En este caso los genero con el botón *Generar Valores*
3. Reemplazar la plantilla o `template` con los valores

Cree una entidad o clase para almacenar cada uno de los valores:

```
  Public Class Datos
        Public Property Port() As Int32
        Public Property Host() As String
        Public Property Meltf() As String
        Public Property Name() As String
        Public Property Y() As String
    End Class
```

Al presionar el botón *Generar Valores* se llena una instancia de la entidad `Datos`

Cree una clase para reemplazar los datos:

```
Public Class Reemplazar


public Function  Reemplaza(ByVal template As String, ByVal valores As Datos  ) As String
    dim resultado as String = template
    resultado = resultado.Replace("[port]",valores.Port)
    resultado = resultado.Replace("[host]",valores.Host)
    resultado = resultado.Replace("[vn]",valores.Name)
    resultado = resultado.Replace("[M]",valores.Meltf)
    resultado = resultado.Replace("/j|n\",valores.Y)

    Return resultado
End Function

End Class
```

Con la función `Reemplaza`, recibe el `template` y los `datos`, y va reemplazando cada dato de la plantilla que nosotros definimos con los valores correspondientes, al final genera un `string` y es lo que retorna la función.

Por último asigno los resultados al ultimo `textbox` para mostrarlos:

```
Private Sub btnReemplazar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReemplazar.Click
        Try     
            me._txtSalida.Text = _r.Reemplaza(me._txtEntrada.Text,_d)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub
```